# Python numpy array: wrong result when mixing int32 and int8

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I saw a very strange behavior in numpy array, when I mixed int32 and int8 arrays in a simple operation, the int32 array element `ct[4,0]` seems to have become 8bit when taking the result of `+= dleng[4]*4`:

```
import numpy as np
In[3]: ct = np.zeros((6,1), np.int32)
In[4]: ct
Out[4]: 
array([[0],
   [0],
   [0],
   [0],
   [0],
   [0]], dtype=int32)
In[5]: dleng = np.zeros((6, 1), np.int8)
In[6]: dleng[0] = 2
dleng[1] = 3
dleng[2] = 4
dleng[3] = 7
dleng[4] = 3
dleng[5] = 5
In[7]: dleng
Out[7]: 
array([[2],
   [3],
   [4],
   [7],
   [3],
   [5]], dtype=int8)
In[8]: ct[4] = 117
In[9]: ct
Out[9]: 
array([[  0],
   [  0],
   [  0],
   [  0],
   [117],
   [  0]], dtype=int32)
In[10]: ct[4,0] += dleng[4]*4
In[11]: ct
Out[11]: 
array([[   0],
   [   0],
   [   0],
   [   0],
   [-127],
   [   0]], dtype=int32)}
```

Does anyone know why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dleng[4]*4` is an *array*:

```
In [94]: dleng[4]
Out[94]: array([3], dtype=int8)

In [95]: dleng[4]*4
Out[95]: array([12], dtype=int8)
```

while `ct[4, 0]` is a *scalar* with type `np.int32`:

```
In [98]: ct[4,0]
Out[98]: 117

In [99]: type(_)
Out[99]: numpy.int32
```

As @WallyBeaver points out, `ct[4,0] += dleng[4]*4` is like `ct[4,0] = ct[4,0] + dleng[4]*4`.  That last expression is a *scalar* plus an *array*.  In that situation, the data type is determined by the *array*, so it ends up being `np.int8`.  There is a note about this in the [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html):

> Mixed scalar-array operations use a different set of casting rules
>   that ensure that a scalar cannot “upcast” an array unless the scalar
>   is of a fundamentally different kind of data (i.e., under a different
>   hierarchy in the data-type hierarchy) than the array. This rule
>   enables you to use scalar constants in your code (which, as Python
>   types, are interpreted accordingly in ufuncs) without worrying about
>   whether the precision of the scalar constant will cause upcasting on
>   your large (small precision) array.

A fix is to write the in-place addition as

```
ct[4,0] += dleng[4,0]*4
```

Comment: Ok this makes sense. Definitely something to pay attention to in the future!

Answer (score 1):

It's because what you are doing is:

```
>>> ct[4,0] += dleng[4]*4
```

Which is actually this:

```
>>> ct[4,0] = ct[4,0] + dleng[4]*4
```

Which produces this:

```
>>> ct[4,0] + dleng[4]*4
array([-127], dtype=int8)
```

Which then does this:

```
>>> ct[4,0] = array([-127], dtype=int8)
```

But is really doing this type conversion under the covers:

```
>>> a.astype(np.int32)
array([-127], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: I don't understand why `ct[4,0] + dleng[4]*4` produces `array([-127], dtype=int8)` --- why is it cast to int8 instead of int32?

Comment: Ah I understand now after seeing both yours and Warren's answers.

Comment: Yeah, `ct[4,0]` is `117`, which is then cast to an `int8` upon addition.